# How do I configure Webpack to support ES7 Decorators

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm using ES7 decorators with my react app but Webpack says they are not supported even though I configured it for ES7 after reading this article 
[Using ES6/7](http://jamesknelson.com/using-es6-in-the-browser-with-babel-6-and-webpack/). I get the error *"Decorators are not supported yet in 6.x pending proposal update"* when trying to run Webpack. 
**webpack.config**
[image]